# override woocommerce.php with custom content for only store homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zurb-foundation

I currently use FoundationPress (Foundation6) as framework and starter theme. It uses woocommerce.php template files to hook into woocommerce functionality but for the life of me I can't figure something out.

I need to add custom content to the stores homepage only, non of the other store pages. Whatever I add to woocommerce.php will appear on all store pages, but I can't figure out what template controls the stores homepage.

The first set of templates I can see are used are the ones that are inthe loop folder and content-product.php. Normally I would just edit archive-product.php but woocommerce.php takes over from this template: see bottom of https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/.

Answer (score 0):

The shop is archive-product. However I did not try FundationPress but it seems that WooCommerce needs in the last version to declare WooCommerce support in themes. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

So first try https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ and check which template is loading. And if its loading page.php instead of Woocommerce template implement the line in functions.php.

Comment: My theme already includes theme support, and sadly that query-monitor doesn't give any further information than I had (useful plugin though). I can just delete woocommerce.php and it defaults back to archive-product.php - but it would hav ebeen useful to see how/what woocommerce.php uses to build the page up.